# Why does my user created reduceX function loop not give me maximum number in the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print("Problem Statement: Accept numbers in list, filter prime numbers, map by multiply by 2, then reduce gives max number")
print()

Prime = lambda No, i : (No % i == 0)
Mult = lambda No : No * 2
Max = lambda No, x : No > x


def filterX(HelperFunction, Data):
    result = list()
    for No in Data:
        for i in range(2, No):
            if HelperFunction(No, i) == True:
                break
        else:
            result.append(No)

    return result

def mapX(HelperFunction, Data):
    result = list()
    for No in Data:
        x = Mult(No)
        result.append(x)

    return result

def reduceX(HelperFunction, Data):
    result = Data[0]
    for i in range(0, len(Data)):
        if Max(Data[i], result) == True:
            result == Data[i]

    return result


def main():
    print("How many numbers do you want to input?")
    value = int(input())
    print()

    Data = list()
    for i in range(0, value, 1):
        x = int(input())
        Data.append(x)

    Data_Filter = filterX(Prime, Data)
    print("The filtered data is:", Data_Filter)

    Data_Map = mapX(Mult, Data_Filter)
    print("The mapped data is:", Data_Map)

    Data_Reduce = reduceX(Max, Data_Map)
    print("The reduced data is:", Data_Reduce)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Been working on this for sometime now. I can't fathom why the reduceX function doesn't return me the maximum number in a list when the lambda function "MaX" works correctly and returns True value. The goal here is take numbers from user, multiply them by 2 then return the maximum number from that list.

Comment: `result == Data[i]`: do you mean `result = Data[i]` instead?

Comment: Omg, yes. It works now. That was too bad from my side. Thank you.